# How does one find out the command line corresponding to GUI app (eg, LibreOffice Writer)?

Tags: command-line, libreoffice

How can I run LibreOffice Writer from the command line? Basically, what is its command and how do I get to know what's the command to run a particular application in general?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Run `libreoffice --writer` to start LibreOffice Writer.

In this case, I guessed that it might be `libreoffice` or similar, so I entered `libre` in a terminal and pressed tab twice. `libreoffice` was one of the options, so I ran that. It started something from which one could choose to go to Writer, Calc, Impress, etc. Since you asked specifically about Writer, I looked at `man libreoffice`, which mentions `-writer` as one of the command line options. Running `libreoffice -writer` worked but resulted in

```
$ libreoffice -writer
Warning: -writer is deprecated.  Use --writer instead.
```

And so I got to `libreoffice --writer`.

In general, one could try things like the following:

- Guess and try names, based on the name of the application. Use Tab-completion for help. Read man pages for options.
- Run the program (using a GUI menu or however else you run it), guess the process name, and check using `ps aux | grep guessed_name`.
- If you know that the program belongs to installed package `X`, run `dpkg -L X`. It will list installed files from package `X`, look for `/usr/bin`, `/bin`, `/sbin`, etc in the output.
- One can find out the process corresponding to a window as follows :

  Run `xprop _NET_WM_PID`, navigate to the target window (without clicking!), and click on it. This will print the PID corresponding to the window, for example

  ```
  _NET_WM_PID(CARDINAL) = 7394
  ```

  Now run `ps -p 7394` (with 7394 replaced by the PID you got) to find out the process name for the given PID.

Comment: Great explanation of the common sense process you used to find the command ... even without Google!

Answer (score 5):

To find a command, try using command auto-complete:

type '**libre**', then press ['**Tab**'], giving you:

```
libreoffice
```

then add ' **--help**', finally giving you:

```
libreoffice --help
```

This will give you ALL the possible options you might need ..

```
(snip)
LibreOffice 3.4  340m1(Build:402)

Usage: soffice [options] [documents...]

Options:
--minimized    keep startup bitmap minimized.
--invisible    no startup screen, no default document and no UI.
--norestore    suppress restart/restore after fatal errors.
--quickstart   starts the quickstart service
--nologo       don't show startup screen.
 :
--writer       create new text document.
--calc         create new spreadsheet document.
--draw         create new drawing.
--impress      create new presentation.
--base         create new database.
:
```

Comment: Exactly what @prateek had answer...

Comment: Don't agree.  That approach involved guessing, and a change find of '-writer'.  I described a more correct and generic method.

Comment: Well, both involve guessing `libre` or `libreoffice`. Is `--help` more generic or correct than `man`?

Comment: The accepted answer is a list of generic strategies that might work in a range of situations. This actually answers the specific question that was asked.

Answer (score 3):

One very easy way which does not involve *any guessing at all*:

- Run `alacarte` (that's 'Main Menu' in the Gnome menu).
- Follow these steps to find out an application's command name:

[image: Finding an application's command name in Gnome's menu editor]

1. Select the application.
2. Click `Properties`.
3. Find the command name for the application in the field `Command`, in this example it is `file-roller`.

Comment: Voted up for not using guesswork! Also, I didn't know about alacarte.

Answer (score 3):

Usually all GUI applications have a launcher icon. *Most* of them are stored in `/usr/share/applications`. These `.desktop` files contain information about application name and their corresponding commands.

A quick hacky way to list all applications and commands is to use *awk* command:

```
awk '{FS = "=";if ($1=="Name") printf("%s => ",$2); if($1=="Exec") {printf("%s\n",$2);nextfile;}}' /usr/share/applications/*.desktop
```

Comment: Great, we can just pipe this to grep and search for any application!

Answer (score 2):

When I access Writer I go into my terminal and type:

> lowriter

This seems to work perfectly and can be repeated for Calc (localc); Draw (lodraw); Base (lobase); Impress (loimpress).  You get the point.

The other wonderful terminal command I learned tonight is this:

> firefox google.com

this will call up Firefox while taking you to the website of your choice or in this case Google.  The more that I play around with the Command Line Interface (CLI) the more that I fall in love with all of the capabilities.

Comment: Please see if the use of `lowriter` is still correct. I tried it just now using 12.04 and with LibreOffice 3.5.4.2 and got this response: `The program 'lowriter' is currently not installed.  You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install libreoffice-writer`

Comment: working on fully up-to-date linux mint dec 2016

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, this can easily be google'ed :p

```
libreoffice --writer
```

Answer (score 1):

On Ubuntu 12.10 and the new libreoffice 4.0, after manual installation, the command is:

libreoffice4.0 --writer

all other commands, like previous answer, are given with the inclusion of 4.0 after libreoffice.

Answer (score 1):

If I have no idea where a program is, or what it is called, and only have the link from the "start menu", I will create a desktop shortcut with right click -> add to desktop. Then I will open the shortcut in a text editor and look for the line starting with "Exec". So, for LibreOffice Calc, I see:

Exec=libreoffice --calc %U

This corresponds to the bash command "libreoffice --calc". The percent-sign has to do with an extended implicit (?) option for exec, which I don't understand but which can be ignored since you're not using Exec.

Answer (score 1):

To start LibreOffice on an existing document, use `xdg-open`.  This not only works for LibreOffice documents but for any file or URL.  `xdg-open` will open the file using your preferred application.

```
xdg-open file-or-url
```

As I usually work from the terminal, my `~/.bash_aliases` has an `alias o=xdg-open`, so it reduces to this:

```
o aDocument.odt
o https://askubuntu.com
```