# How to open a file with LibreOffice Writer from Terminal?

Tags: command-line, libreoffice

I use LibreOffice Writer a lot, but I really do hate getting around in a GUI, I much prefer the CLI, so is there any way to open a file using LibreOffice Writer through the Terminal?

Comment: Nearly a duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/80977/how-does-one-find-out-the-command-line-corresponding-to-gui-app-eg-libreoffice.

Comment: `libreoffice --help` @pilot6 answer also works for `calc`, `draw`, `base`

Comment: @ParanoidPanda xdg-open?

Answer (score 82, accepted):

You can do it by

```
libreoffice --writer file.odt
```

If it is an `odt` file, you can open it just by

```
libreoffice file.odt
```

Some file formats can be opened by different LO applications, then you need to specify which one to use.

Comment: Short and powerful =)

Comment: If its a csv or xls file then ` libreoffice --calc /path/to/file.csv`. You can get more info by `man libreoffice`

Comment: To launch a brand new file like this you need to first create it, `touch file.odt && libreoffice --writer file.odt`

Comment: If you want a new file, there is no need to `touch` it. You can just start `libreoffice --writer` then save the file after you edit it.

Comment: I get an error when opening files straight with the --writer option. but when i run touch first it works fine.

Comment: For later versions and/or manually-installed versions, you may need to include the version number. In my case, it is required to be done as follows: `libreoffice6.1 --writer`

Comment: For my Mac installation there's no libreoffice command in my $PATH and `find /Applications/LibreOffice.app/  -name 'libreoffice*'` comes up empty.

Comment: This site has nothing to do with Mac installations.

Answer (score 5):

The more general solution is `xdg-open`.  This not only works for LibreOffice documents, but for any file or URL:

```
xdg-open file-or-url
```

opens file-or-url using your preferred application.

If you normally work from the terminal, then having `alias o=xdg-open` in  `~/.bash_aliases` makes life simple:

```
o my-document.odt
o https://askubuntu.com
```

You may then also enjoy `sr` (surfraw) for rapid web searches from the command-line.

Answer (score 2):

In case you need to open a file in LibreOffice in read-only mode it's

```
libreoffice --view file.odt
```