# How to open LibreOffice Impress from Terminal?

Tags: command-line, libreoffice

I'm trying to open LibreOffice Impress from the terminal. My question is similar to [How to open a file with LibreOffice Writer from Terminal?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/659741/how-to-open-a-file-with-libreoffice-writer-from-terminal). I love using terminal.

I tried with:

```
libreoffice --impress
```

But it doesn't do the trick.

Comment: I tried `libreoffice --impress`, `loffice --impress`, and`loimpress` and all work on 16.04

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You haven't said what release, but `loffice` opens it on my 19.04 box.

*options of `loffice` include*

> File open arguments:
>
> The arguments create an empty document of specified kind. Only one of
>   them may be used in one command line. If filenames are specified after
>   an argument, then it tries to open those files in the specified
>   component.

```
   --writer            Creates an empty Writer document.
   --calc              Creates an empty Calc document.
   --draw              Creates an empty Draw document.
   --impress           Creates an empty Impress document.
   --base              Creates a new database.
   --global            Creates an empty Writer master (global) document.
   --math              Creates an empty Math document (formula).
   --web               Creates an empty HTML document.
```

*from [`man loffice`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/loffice.1.html)*

Answer (score 3):

The simpliest method is to run LibreOffice Impress with

```
loimpress
```

command as it is installed with [`libreoffice-impress` package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic-updates/amd64/libreoffice-impress/filelist).

Also note other commands:

- LibreOffice Calc `localc`
- LibreOffice from template `lofromtemplate`
- LibreOffice Writer `loweb`
- LibreOffice Math `lomath`
- LibreOffice Draw `lodraw`
- LibreOffice Base `lobase`
- LibreOffice Writer `lowriter`
- LibreOffice  `loffice`