# How to create .odt file using terminal on Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: 20.04, libreoffice

I tried the method given at: https://askubuntu.com/a/659742/1454335

If I am using: `libreoffice --writer FinalProposal.odt` then, I am getting an error shown [in this figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YLYLr.png).

If I am using `touch FinalProposal.odt && libreoffice --writer FinalProposal.odt` then, it is working fine and I am able to create new file.

I want to know, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

The command you use is for opening a file that already exists. If there is no file with that name, you get the error saying that the file does not exist.

To open libreoffice writer with a new empty text, do `libreoffice --writer` and give the file name when saving.